# How can I change the icons of window button?

Tags: 12.10, icons

How can I change the icons of window button? Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will involve changing your theme. But what you can do is create your own theme.

Its not as hard as it seems:

1. copy a base theme
2. replace the images currently used with the ones you want to use
3. choose the theme you just created in appearance settings.

You can find a more detailed [instruction about changing Ubuntu window icons](http://www.sudo-juice.com/how-to-change-ubuntu-window-icons/) here

Answer (score 4):

By changing your Themes (`System Settings > Appearance > Theme drop-down options`) you change the icons you see in Nautilus and other programs.

Comment: I don't want to change the theme.